# Getting Percentage and Total from SELECT GROUP BY Mysql

Tags: mysql

After multiple searches I couldn't find a fit solution that would work in my case.

I have the following table:

```
id  category    entry_date
1   Suggestion  01/01/2019
2   Suggestion  05/01/2019
3   Compliment  05/01/2019
4   Complaint   12/02/2019
5   Suggestion  09/10/2019
6   Compliment  23/11/2019
```

I need to show the number of each category and the percentage of each (based on the total entries). The 'where' will limit a date range - but I'm assuming that here it doesn't matter. This is my expected result:

```
Category       Totals   % of Total Entries
Compliment     2        ˜34%
Complaint      1        16%
Suggestion     3        60%
```

Here is the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT category, 
 COUNT(*) AS total, 
 ROUND(COUNT(category)*100 / (SELECT COUNT(*))) AS pct 
 FROM (Mytable) 
 WHERE `entry_date` >= '2018-01-01' AND `entry_date` <= '2019-12-31' 
 GROUP BY category ORDER BY category ASC
```

With this the pct is relative to each category (so: 200,100,300), and not the total.

I'm using MySQL 5.7. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT count can take time, so it will not be fast on big tables

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`id` int, `category` varchar(10), `entry_date` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`id`, `category`, `entry_date`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Suggestion', '01/01/2019'),
>     (2, 'Suggestion', '05/01/2019'),
>     (3, 'Compliment', '05/01/2019'),
>     (4, 'Complaint', '12/02/2019'),
>     (5, 'Suggestion', '09/10/2019'),
>     (6, 'Compliment', '23/11/2019')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `category`,     COUNT(*) AS cnt,
>     100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) AS percent   FROM Table1 GROUP BY `category`
> ```
>
> ```
> category   | cnt |  percent
> :--------- | --: | -------:
> Suggestion |   3 | 50.00000
> Compliment |   2 | 33.33333
> Complaint  |   1 | 16.66667
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7059cfa3f2a9ace8da2fd4947ba53c9)*

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do this with window functions in MySQL 8.0:

```
with cte as (
  select category, count(*) over (partition by category) as subtotal,
    count(*) over () as total from following_table )
select category, subtotal, 
  concat(round(subtotal*100/total), '%') as `% of Total Entries` 
from cte group by category;
```

Output:

```
+------------+----------+--------------------+
| category   | subtotal | % of Total Entries |
+------------+----------+--------------------+
| Complaint  |        1 | 17%                |
| Compliment |        2 | 33%                |
| Suggestion |        3 | 50%                |
+------------+----------+--------------------+
```

In MySQL 5.7, do it with two queries. The first to get the total, then the second to use that result to calculate the percentage per group.